# Is there a firefox plugin or greasemonkey script that will alter the styling of textareas to look like a code editor?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I have to use a specific CMS to manage multiple websites.  The forms that the html templates, javascript files, and css documents get entered in are just basic textarea elements, with no nice code editor.

Is there something I can add to my firefox installation to make it do colours and indents automatically?

Comment: Why don't you just edit in your preferred editor and then paste into the web form?

Comment: Following on from what user terdon says, this may be useful: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/its-all-text/

Comment: Why don't I?  Because I don't want to.  It's more clicking and farting around.  Hey, why use a computer at all right?  Just write everything down on paper and put it in a filing cabinet.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Firefox extension: [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/)

"It's All Text!" will take any textarea in your browser and place it into your favourite text editor. You can edit to your heart's content. Then when you save and close the file everything you did is put *back* into the textarea! Voila.

You can configure "It's All Text" to use keyboard shortcuts and/or add a clickable button to textareas.